# Which path to PHP for cronjob?

Tags: php

I'm running a PHP script as a cronjob. I need PHP 5.4 or greater. Which path should I use? I have:

> (uiserver):z2309ii3ee:~ > whereis php
>   php: /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php5.4 /usr/bin/php5.5 /usr/bin/php5.4-cli /usr/bin/php5.5-cli /usr/lib/php /usr/lib/php.ini /usr/lib/php5.4 /usr/lib/php5.5 /usr/lib/php.ini-nourl /usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php5.4 /usr/local/bin/php5.5 /usr/local/lib/php.ini-nourl /usr/include/php /usr/include/php5.4 /usr/include/php5.5 /usr/local/php /usr/share/php

The online help of my hoster says I should use `/usr/local/bin/php5`, but that's PHP 5.2.17.

Why should I not use `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5.4` with a cronjob? That is the version run when I call a script in my browser (says `echo PHP_BINARY;`).

Comment: Whoever voted to close: Why is this "opinion based"? If there is a reason to prefer one PHP instance over another, then I'd like to know that reason, but if all variants of PHP can be used with a cronjob, then that is not an opinion but an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/usr/lib` usually contains libraries and other files that are needed by a program but not the program itself (the executable file(s)). The programs stay in `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local/bin` or subdirectories of these.

I would try to `ls -l` or `file` with `/usr/bin/php5.5`, `/usr/bin/php5.5-cli` or `/usr/local/bin/php5.5` to find out if they are executable files or directories. If they are directories, it's possible they have the executable files inside their own `bin` subdirectories (i.e. `/usr/bin/php5.5/bin/php` and similar).

After I find the executable file(s) I need I would run it (them) with option `--version` to see if it is the version I need.

Answer (score 1):

If it's working, use newest version (or that is compatible with your code).

Comment: Just use the `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5.4`. Their documentation probably still dates from the moment they did not yet have different PHP versions to choose from

Comment: @mvbrakel Why 5.4 and not 5.5?

Comment: Because his site runs on 5.4 an he probably tested his code on that. 5.5 is clearly possible as well. PHP however is not always 100% backwards compatible